# Config order in python, flask

Tags: python, flask, config

experts! I need a piece of your experience.
In one Flask app, I need to take config params in a special order. First - from the environment, if it is there if no - from config class. Don't ask, why)

I've figured out two options.

First - to use a function, and replace all `current_app.config` with it.
Something like this

```py
def get_config(name):
    return os.getenv(name, current_app.config.get(name))
```

Second - to use a mini descriptor for config classes.
Something like this:

```py
class ConfigOrder:

    def __init__(self, name, default):
        self.name = name
        self.default = default

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return os.getenv(self.name, self.default)


class MondayConfig:
    PARAM = ConfigOrder('PARAM', 'value_1')


class TuesdayConf:
    PARAM = ConfigOrder('PARAM', 'value_2')
```

And I've stuck) I lack experience(. Can anyone write their own opinion? Where I can shoot my leg?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having with this?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to replace all `current_app.config`s if you just replace the existing configuration with the new one returned by your `get_config`? Or use the facilities offered by [flask.Config](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Config)?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm not sure, what option is more correct. And I've never used descriptors before, so I don't know, what hidden problems I can face.

Comment: @teprrr There is no one place, where configs could be got and used. There are `current_app.config` everywhere. Alas, refactoring is not option currently.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? With environment variable PARAM:

```
(pvenv) code % echo $PARAM1
environ_param
(pvenv) code %
```

and then update your config parameters from the environment if they exist:

```
>>> class AppConfig:
...     PARAM1 = 'config_param_1'
...     PARAM2 = 'config_param_2'
... 
>>> app.config.from_object(AppConfig)
>>> {k:v for k,v in app.config.items() if k.startswith('PARAM')}
{'PARAM1': 'config_param_1', 'PARAM2': 'config_param_2'}
>>> for k in app.config:
...     app.config[k] = os.environ.get(k) if os.environ.get(k) else app.config[k]
... 
>>> {k:v for k, v in app.config.items() if k.startswith('PARAM')}
{'PARAM1': 'environ_param', 'PARAM2': 'config_param_2'}
```